# Linear Transformation of a vector from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider $a = \{(0, 2), (2, -1)\}$ and $b = \{(1, 1, 0), (0, 0, -1), (1, 0, 1)\}$ Basis of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$. Let

$$[S]^\alpha_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\4&0\\0&-4\end{bmatrix}$$

Give the expression for $S(x, y)$.

What I've tried:

1st step: Make the product of [1] by the vector $(x, y)$.

- The result is $(2x, 4x, -4y)$ - I'm writing in this notation to preserve efforts in doing a matrix here

2nd step: Multiply the first element from (1st step) by the basis vector $(1, 1, 0)$ from $b$, and the element of the second line of the result in (1st step) by the second basis vector from $b$, and then, for the third element too.

3rd step: Unify in just one vector

- The result is $(2x-4y, 2x, -4x-4y)$

The correct answear is $(y-(3/2)x, y+(x/2), -3x-2y)$

I'm not getting how I can approach the correct answer.
I appreciate your help

Comment: Please [don’t use images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem) instead of [typing your formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final result is not $f(x,y)$ but $f(x(0,2)+y(2,-1))$.

Apply your result to $(u,v)=x(0,2)+y(2,-1)=(2y,2x-y)$, i.e. replace $y$ by $\frac u2$ and $x$ by $\frac{v+y}2=\frac{u+2v}4$ in
$$f(2y,2x-y)=(2x-4y, 2x, -4x-4y),$$ and you will find indeed $$f(u,v)=\left(v-\frac32u, v+\frac u2, -3u-2v\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!